# how to send the DB fetched values to frontend using selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, sql

I wrote a program where values are coming from sql database.Now i want to send those values to frontend using selenium.
say it is an pincode i fetched from Database but now if locate the element where i want to store that fetched otp how will I do?.sendkeys in selenium is not accepting
Piece of code I wrote :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class JavaConnect2SQL {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        
        try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//String url="jdbc:sqlserver://LAPTOP-F0E1C4GT\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=BikeStores;";
//String user="sa";
//String password="NewPassword@123";

String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=sa;password=NewPassword@123;databaseName=BikeStores";
//connServer.connect(url);


    Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    System.out.println("Connected");
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

    String query = "select  TOP 1 pincode from pintable";
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()){
       System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("https://indialends.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Personal Loan")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.name("li_display_name")).toString(rs.getString(1));
        //Belowline->Is my confusion??
driver.findElement(By.name("pincode")).sendKeys("122018");//this 122018 i am writing by sendkeys but i want this to be filled from SQL itself

} }catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("Oops,there is error");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
        }
}
```

PLease help and suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.name("pincode")).sendKeys(rs.getString(1));
```

Is this what you looking for

Comment: @ Ravneet kaur, we should upvote an answer if it helped.

Comment: @RavneetKaur you don't have enough reputation you accound accept the answer by clicking the tick sign near to answer . Once you have enough reputation upvote and accept the answer :) if it helps Vishal Thank you .. :)

Comment: yes sure vishal

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest to make it less **messy**:

- Make few generic db connection/retrieval functions
- if data retrieval is not dynamic , create separate script to populate a data source like an file: json, csv or excel to further use directly in simpler way in tests.

Comment: i will try for this